# Как навесить обработчик на кнопку в кастомной директиве

Tags: angularjs

Есть готовый html:

```
<div ng-repeat="notification in vm.notifications" class="notifications">
        <notification notification="notification"></notification>
</div>
```

В нём отрисовываются следующие директивы:

```
app.directive('notification', function($compile){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                notification: "=notification"
            },
            link: function(scope, element) {
                var temp = "<notifications" + scope.notification.type.normalCase() + ">";
                var link = $compile(temp);
                var content = link(scope);
                element.append(content);
            }
        }
    });

    app.directive('notificationsStudentRequest', function(){
        return {
            template: '<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible"><button type="button" class="close" ng-click="vm.deleteNotification(notification)"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>Запрос на участие в курсе: "{{notification.payload.course.name}}"</div>',
            restrict: 'EC',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true
        }
    });

    app.directive('notificationsStudentRequestAccepted', function(){
        return {
            template: '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible"><button type="button" class="close" ng-click="vm.deleteNotification(notification)"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>[{{ notification.createdAt | date}}] Запрос на участие в курсе: "{{notification.payload.course.name}}" был принят</div>',
            restrict: 'EC',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true
        }
    });

    app.directive('notificationsStudentRequestRejected', function(){
        return {
            template: '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible"><button type="button" class="close" ng-click="vm.deleteNotification(notification)"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>[{{ notification.createdAt | date}}] Запрос на участие в курсе: "{{notification.payload.course.name}}" был отклонен</div>',
            restrict: 'EC',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true
        }
    });
```

В директивах есть кнопка на удаление элемента. Функция выглядит следующим образом:

```
vm.deleteNotification = function(notification){
    vm.notifications.splice(vm.notifications.indexOf(notification), 1);
}
```

```
<div ng-repeat="notification in vm.notifications" class="notifications">
        Если кнопку создать тут, то она работает отлично и удаляет всё как положенно. Тоисть функция отрабатывает.
</div>
```

Но если кнопка указана в шаблоне директивы, то она просто не активна. Подскажите почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании синтаксиса `controllerAs` ссылка на контроллер сохраняется в скоп.

Изолированный скоп не наследуется от текущего скопа, поэтому у него нет доступа к полям текущего скопа и соответственно к полю `vm`.

Решений может быть множество:

1. использовать [`$parent`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$parent): `$parent.vm.delete(...)`
2. передавать ссылку на функцию в изолированный скоп
3. не использовать изолированный скоп
4. навешивать обработчик с помощью jqLite
5. посылка события
6. линковать сразу к родительскому скопу

и т.д.

Comment: а можно пример с $parent? Не могу сообразить как его правильно использовать в данном контексте.

Comment: @V.Rotenberh, я же в ответе уже добавил пример: `$parent.vm.delete(...)` вместо просто обращения `vm.delete(...)`